# Is this syntactically correct code to create a box plot

Tags: r, boxplot

I've created/attempted to create a box plot using the code below and was previously receiving the following error message

> 'Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop =
>   drop,  :    object 'Nationality' not found'

I played around with some functions and got some output, which I believe is valid. However, I'm a programming novice and don't want to draw incorrect conclusions based on bad code. I loaded the data, Rating and Nationality are column names as you can imagine, with Nationality being the first column.

For context, 'Rating' is continuous and 'Nationality' is a categorical variable. I've posted below what I've come up with as a solution. Please, correct if necessary:

```
Nationality<-soccer_data[,1]

boxplot(
  formula = Rating~Nationality,
  data    = soccer_data,
  col     = Nationality
 )
```

Comment: You've got a backtick on your definition of Nationality...if you remove it, I bet your code will work.

Comment: You're getting this error because of color attribute, try to use dataset$nationality instead of Nationality, boxplot(formula = Rating~Nationality,data = soccer_data,col = soccer_data$nationality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Nationality` for colour. Fixed now thanks to @ Casper

```r
soccer_data <- data.frame(
    Rating = runif(100),
    Nationality = sample(c("Earth", "Mars"), 100, replace=TRUE)
)

boxplot(
    formula = Rating ~ Nationality,
    data    = soccer_data, 
    col = c("Earth"="blue", "Mars"="red")
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Deletion is not the correct solution, col attribute is responsible for box-plot color.